# Relationship between product and stock and user

Tags: sql, relationship, entity-relationship, diagram

Hello I am trying to do the following relationship:

I have a stock of **Components**, each component has a stock, and a user can have more than one component (if he has stock), but a component can only be that user.
In other words, as I have a component stock
that is:

10 SSD'S, I would have to have 10 different component id's to use the user id in the component table

so I don't know how I can resolve this relationship.
that is, a component of id 1, has 10 in stock,
10 users can have these components, but I wanted to have a way to link the component with the user.

[image]

or this:

[image]

Comment: Each user can have many components that's one user to many components and stock components can have at least one stock that's one to one or one components to many stocks and a category can contain many components that's one category to many components .

Comment: the problem is that this way I would have 10 different id's for the same type of component, that is, I have 10 identical components, but I need to link to 10 different users.

Comment: So you mean  one component can belong to many users ? What type of systems do you plan to build

Comment: basically it would work like this, I have 100 DELL monitors in my stock, and I need to distribute these 10 monitors to 100 users, but that way I would have to have 100 records from the same monitor (dell same model etc etc)
and 100 records in stock?

Comment: Look at the edited answer this structure means that if you distribute the 100 Dell monitors to 10 users you will have 10 records in stock and 10 records in user_has_components that's all and the components will still contain one record

Answer (score 0):

The table of components should contain
-id

-name

-category_id

The user_has_component should contain

-user_id

-Component_id

The table of categories should contain

-id

-name

The table of stock should contain

-id

-Quantity

-component_id

-user_id

The table of users should contain at least

-id

And other user information

Comment: the problem is that this way I would have 10 different id's for the same type of component, that is, I have 10 identical components, but I need to link to 10 different users.

Comment: that is, I have 10 equal monitors in my stock, but I need 10 different users.

Comment: that way I would have 10 monitor id's + 10 id's in stock.

Comment: If you want many users to link with one component you can add an other table contains -user_id and -component_id

Comment: And for the stock you will need to add user_id attribute to the structure that I gave you in my answer